# Associativity of wedge product in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I'm reading a book on [differential forms](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/diffforms.pdf) to try to understand wedge products. Given two vectors $u$ and $v$, the wedge product is defined $u\wedge v = u^Tv - v^Tu$.

It is stated that the wedge product is associative, but I'm having trouble proving it. For example,
$$\begin{split}
u\wedge (v\wedge w) &= u\wedge(v^Tw - w^Tv)\\
  &= u\wedge(v^Tw) - u\wedge(w^Tv)\\
  &= u^Tv^Tw - w^Tvu - u^Tw^Tv + v^Twu\\
  &= u^Tv^Tw - u^Tw^Tv + v^Twu - w^Tvu,
\end{split}$$
but
$$\begin{split}
  (u\wedge v)\wedge w &= (u^Tv - v^Tu)\wedge w\\
  &= (u^Tv)\wedge w - (v^Tu)\wedge w\\
  &= v^Tuw - wu^Tv - u^Tvw + w^Tv^Tu,
\end{split}$$
and they're clearly not the same. Is it because associativity does not apply for this definition?

Comment: You only defined the wedge product of two vectors. But $v\wedge w$ is not a vector. You haven't defined what is $u\wedge(v\wedge w)$.

Comment: @EclipseSun You're right, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The wedge product of two vectors is a multilinear function. The sign is in front of each term depends if the indices are an odd or even permutation.

$
\vec{u} \wedge \vec{v} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (sgn \sigma) a^{\sigma(1)...\sigma(n)} (\vec{e_{\sigma(1)}} \otimes ... \otimes \vec{e_{\sigma(n)}})
$
n is the sum of the dimensions of the vectors spaces of $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$.

In this case, the wedge product of two vectors, each in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If  $\vec{u}, \vec{v} \in V$

$
\vec{u} \wedge \vec{v} : V^* \times V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
\vec{u} \wedge \vec{v} = a^{1,2} (\vec{e_1} \otimes \vec{e_2}) - a^{2,1} (\vec{e_2} \otimes \vec{e_1})
$

It takes, for example, this argument and spits out a number

$
\vec{x}^* \otimes \vec{y}^* \in V^* \times V^* \\
\vec{x}^* \otimes \vec{y}^* = b_{i,j} (\vec{e^i} \otimes \vec{e^j})
$

So, 
$
(\vec{u} \wedge \vec{v})(\vec{x}^* \otimes \vec{y}^*) = a^{1,2} b_{1,2} - a^{2,1} b_{2,1}
$

The wedge product of 3 vectors, each in $V$ acts on an element in $V^* \times V^* \times V^*$.
So to show associativity, you have to act on a (0,3)-type tensor and show the components are the same.

Comment: Thanks for writing up an answer, though I can't verify its correctness. I was hoping that I could minimally approach wedge product properties (as it was tangentially related to my study), but I see now that it's not the case.

Comment: In you initial question, where did you get that definition from?

Comment: it was https://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/diffforms.pdf on page 10, when they introduced wedge products.

Comment: You can't prove associativity from this definition because it applies to two vectors. The wedge product of two vectors is an antisymmetric matrix. You have to expand the definition of what the wedge is. Take a sidebar from this manuscript and Google "Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W Tu". This is covered well with examples in the beginning chapters. You'll see what I'm talking about.